# Can't send transaction using web3

Tags: python, blockchain, web3py

I'm trying to send a transaction via fantom networkusing this code. This code for for me on polygon network but for some reason it doesn't work on fantom network. This token contract has transfer and transferFrom and none of them works with my code.

Token contract: https://ftmscan.com/address/0x667afbb7d558c3dfd20fabd295d31221dab9dbc2#code

```
def sendToken(_from, _to, _balance, _from_privet):
transaction = contract.functions.transferFrom(_from,str(_to), w3.toWei(_balance, 'ether')) \
    .buildTransaction({'chainId': 250,
                       'gas': 585901,
                       'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount(_from)})
signed_txn = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, private_key=_from_privet)
try:
    tx_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_txn.rawTransaction)
    recipt_hash = w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(binascii.hexlify(tx_hash).decode())
    print(binascii.hexlify(tx_hash).decode())
```

but for some reason transaction fail and I couldn't understand why.
There is hash for this transaction.
0x9a87a2db4776dab986f18cd0e7f832ecdcaa48793be740c79c0f0b1a128f28b5
[image]

Answer (score -1):

https://dashboard.tenderly.co/tx/fantom/0x9a87a2db4776dab986f18cd0e7f832ecdcaa48793be740c79c0f0b1a128f28b5

from nips.sol

--snip

```
  function _transfer(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) private {
        require(sender != address(0), "ERC20: transfer from the zero address");
        require(recipient != address(0), "ERC20: transfer to the zero address");
        require(amount > 0, "Transfer amount must be greater than zero");
        if(sender != owner() && recipient != owner())
          require(amount <= _maxTxAmount, "Transfer amount exceeds the 
    maxTxAmount.");
```

--snip

looks like sender was not owner.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).